# Using a result to index a data.frame

Tags: r, indexing

I have a  data.frame named pp that looks like this:

```
> head(pp)    
            X02R  X03N  X04K  X04N  X04R  X06I  X06N  X08J  X08P  X09O  X11O   
1961-02-28  42.0  43.0  96.2  10.2  13.5  42.4  21.1  79.1   2.7  15.2  14.3  
1962-02-28  17.1  22.7  27.9 140.7  10.0  36.7   8.2  47.2  28.5  31.5  24.0
```

Separately I am calculating

```
dmax<-douro[which(douro[,3]== max(douro[,3])),]
```

which, for example gives me:

```
 > dmax   
   name catch corre.gauge  
31 X04K Douro  -0.5157648
```

Now I want to use the result `dmax[1]` (the name) to plot the respective column of data from pp. In this case I would like to plot `pp$X04K`. How can I do that in an automatic way (because I am going to repeat this process several times resulting in different columns from pp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joran just edited your post which means I will be asked to reload the page because an answer has been provided... Getting to the heart of the matter, you can extract the column name and pass it on to `[` like so:

```
pp[, as.character(dmax[1,1])]
```

The comma is not mandatory but play around with it to see how the layout of the result changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering I tried that but I always get an error:`> pp[, dmax[1]]`
`Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'`
`> pp[dmax[1]]`
`Error in `[.default`(pp, dmax[1]) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: this is odd,  using `pp[,dmax[1,1]]` I don't get an error but it extracts the wrong column. However if I do `dmax[1,1]` I get the right name... also `> class(dmax[1,1])`
`[1] "factor"`

Comment: Ah, then do: `pp[, as.character(dmax[1,'name'])]`.

Comment: @sbg, try coercing to character: `as.character(dmax[1,1])`. Can you show us the result of `str(dmax)`?

Comment: Thanks @Harlan for spotting this.